# Python Igraph : Decompose graph based on giant component

Tags: python, r, igraph

How can I decompose a graph based on the largest cluster size by using Python ?

Here's what it looks like in R

```
G <- decompose.graph(g)[[which(cl$csize==max(cl$csize))]]
```

- g is the graph that contain multiple clusters
- cl is the cluster of g

Comment: have you tried the igraph python official documentation? there is lots of goodies there!

Answer (score 6):

Something like this:

```
largest = g.clusters().giant()
```

`g.clusters()` returns a `VertexClustering` object that represents the division of the graph into its connected components, and its `giant()` method simply extracts the largest cluster into its own graph.